Ignite Memory/Disk Usage
I am trying to figure out how the disk/memory pages are used. I did find a bunch of (old?) documentation (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/IGNITE/Ignite+Multi-Tier+Storage+-+under+the+hood) but I am still not clear on how to account for the memory and disk used and more importantly what to do to reduce it.
With a simple object (see below), 88.8GB are allocated for 317 millions of objects.
I have the following  key, value, all the fields of the key and the value are part of a query and the key is indexed.
key = 3 long + 2 ints ==> 38+24 = 32 bytes
value = 3 long  ==> 3*8 ==> 24 bytes
So a particular data point takes 56 bytes. Hence 317,462,594 should take 16.6 GB
If my understanding of the binary marshaller is correct I end up with
key = 24 byte of header + 32 bytes of data + 5 bytes of type (because 5 fields) + 10 bytes for offset (because 2bytes per field) ==> 71 bytes
value = (following the same logic) => 57 bytes
Therefore only counting the binary marshaller the 317 millions should be around 37.8 GB
So we all know that the binary marshaller is not efficient for small types only composed or primitive types. This is even documented in https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/IGNITE/IEP-2%3A+Binary+object+format+improvements (By the way, does someone know what is the status of the binary marshaller with ignite 3.0?)
So all the fields are part of a query. So I can admit that it doubles so 75.7 GB. But I am still missing 13GB. that are not accounted for.
Please note that we tried to use externalizable the gain is minimum because the bulk of the the memory used does not seem to come from the actual object itself but from all the data management structures.
Now here are the actual questions:

is the above reasoning more of less ok?
is there anything in ignite 3.0 that will reduce the above overhead?
is there something I can do on the short term to reduce the disk occupation (memory might be ok but persistence is a problem as we keep different runs)


There is additional overhead per entry and per table, see https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/administrators-guide/capacity-planning
